# Is it possible to use KVO to obtain a sub-array of an array?

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of objects which have an enum as one of their properties, I would like to obtain a filtered array based upon the value of the enum i.e. the returned array contains only objects which have a specified enum value.

I was wondering if KVO could be used as a tidy way of doing this, but haven't found anything suggesting it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [filtering the array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a) using [a predicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795):

```
NSArray * filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfProperty == %d", theEnumValue]];
```

The string for the predicate names the property you're interested in, the value to which it should be compared, and the relationship the two must have for the predicate to evaluate as true.